# Is it possible to create 2 50% columns with a 5 pixel margin without specifying exact widths for each column?

Tags: html, css

How would I create a simple 2-column layout with a 5 pixel margin between them?

Like so:

[image]

It's tricky because if you try and set both column's widths to 50%, and then try to add a margin to one or both of them, one will get pushed below the other so that it can fill the 50%.

Comment: Could you add a little more detail? Do the columns have to be equal height? What is the minimum browser versions you wish to support? Fixed width or fluid? Maybe draw a picture?

Comment: @thirtydot: No, I'm not concerned about height at the moment. Minimum browser versions? Anything with a significant market share; the more the better. "Fixed" to 50%.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven´t provided a lot of information, but a simple but ugly solution would be to use wrapper `divs`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #right {
            float: right;
            width: 50%;
        }
        #left {
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
        }
        .left {
            margin-right: 2px;
            background-color: #F9F;
        }
        .right {
            margin-left: 3px;
            background-color: #9FF;
        }
        </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="left"><div class="left">Left</div></div>
  <div id="right"><div class="right">Right</div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ugly because of the extra `divs`, but that´s hard to avoid when you start mixing units (pixels and %).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NLrF4/1/ yep... seems to work. i actually don't mind the extra divs. i'm building a templating engine that will abstract all that nastiness away, so i'm trying to figure out how to do all these things in raw html and then i can wrap it in prettiness.

Answer (score 1):

For almost any sort of multi-column layout, *[Ultimate multi-column liquid layouts](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-multi-column-liquid-layouts-em-and-pixel-widths)* is my go-to template.

Comment: none of those do specifically what i asked. what makes it difficult is the 5 pixel margin. as soon as you set the width to 50%, and then try to add a margin, one of the columns will get pushed down so that it can take up the full 50%.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would start with

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="left" style="float:left; width:50%">content</div>
  <div id="right" style="margin:left 5px;">content</div>
  <div id="floatcap" style="clear:both:"/> //causes container to grow to the height of left   column if left column is bigger
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YKR5Y/ doesn't work. there's no gap between the red and blue divs (tested in ff 3.6)